# Applying distortion to Bézier surface

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, image-processing, bezier-curve

I am trying to simulate the image warp effect, that is used in Adobe Photoshop.

The rectangular image is warped according to a cubic Bézier surface (in 2D, all Z components are 0). Having any Bézier surface, **vertical distortion** $d \in[0,1]$ can be applied to it.

**Left**: input bézier surface, $d=0$, **Right**: output surface,  $d=0.8$

[image]
[image]
[image]

Do you have any idea, what is done to the Bézier surface (16 points), when converting from the version on the left to the output on the right?

Comment: Try http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I tried, still no answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the $y$-coordinates of the Bezier patch control points are being left unchanged, and the $x$-values are being "tapered". When I say "tapered", I mean that the upper edge of the patch is being shrunk inwards, the lower edge is being expanded outwards, and the mid-height curve is being left unchanged.

I don't really know what the "$d=0.8$" value means. You say $d=0$ corresponds to no tapering, and I'd guess that $d=1$ is very strong tapering, where the top edge of the patch gets shrunk to a point (which means that the lower edge will double in width).

Let's assume that the left-hand patch has corners at $(-1,-1)$, $(-1,1)$, $(1,-1)$, $(1,1)$. If my guess about $d$ is correct, then the required transformation is:
$$
T(x,y) = \big( (1-dy)x,  y\big)
$$
It's easy to confirm that:
$$
T(x,0) = (x,0) \quad \text{for all } x
$$
$$
T(1,-1) = (1+d, -1)
$$
$$
T(1,1) = (1-d, 1)
$$
and so on.

Comment: Do you know how I can achieve this type of image transformation through hard programming.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "hard" programming. Just code the formula for $T(x,y)$